# Copy Status Message in Teradata

Tags: teradata

IS it possible to copy status message in teradata?
(I don't want to type them everytime, for example when I try to google the error message)

Comment: Could you clarify which status messages you are referring to?

Comment: I am referring to any error messages that appears in the status bar. Is it possible to do a quick copy, because I can't use the cursor to mark the text and then do the copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the tool that you are using to query Teradata will determine how these messages are exposed to the end user:

- BTEQ and the Teradata Load/Unload utility log files will contain the error code and the error message returned via the CLI.
- SQL Assistant should capture the error code and possibly the error message in the SQL History file. This is also stored in an Access Database that you can access separately from SQL Assistant if you have Microsoft Access installed on your system.
- AtanaSuite QueryTool captures both the error code and the error message in the SQL History. This is stored in a flat file that you can open with your text editor separately.
- Stored Procedures - It is not possible to capture the exact error message within a stored procedure but you can get the error code and log it to a log table in your error handler.

If I recall correctly there is a table named DBC.ErrorText that also contains the tokenized error messages that you can query. Lastly, the Teradata Manuals have an entire book dedicated to Messages that includes the Teradata Database messages returned for errors.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Bob, thank you again for the impeccable response.
All I wanted to know is there some quick way to copy error message from the status bar when I quickly want to google the error. This would help me to not loose focus on solving the problem because now I have to spend some time until I type the message. Of course, I don't waste a lot of time, but simple copy would optimize my performance :) 
Additionaly could you suggest me some some client for the SSH other than Putty. It would be great it that client could do windows splitting. I am using Windows xp. I didn't find anything satisfying on Google

Comment: Poderosa and KiTTy are two SSH alternatives to PuTTY. Poderosa will give you a tabbed window. KiTTY is closer to PuTTY but has the ability for a transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

Press PF11 to get the message to display in a popup -> Then CTRL-C to copy - Then paste to notepad- you will see entire contents of popup like this:

---

### Teradata SQL Assistant

### [3807] Object 'DBC.ErrorText' does not exist.

### OK

You can then copy the pertinent error message from this:
 [3807] Object 'DBC.ErrorText' does not exist.

This was the message in my status bar originally.